# Complex Conjugation question

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I had a complex analysis exam yesterday, and one of the questions is bothering me.

Suppose $f(z)$ is an entire function. Show that $g(z) = (f(z^*))^*$ is also entire. Here $^*$ indicates complex conjugate.
The problem said to "think about Cauchy-Riemann"

The next part asked to find $g(z)$ for each $f(z)$:

$f(z) = c_0 + c_1 z + c_2 z^2 + ... + c_n z^n$

$f(z) = \sin(z)$

Is it not true that $g(z)$ is just $f(z)$ in both of these cases?

Thanks in advance for the guidance.

Comment: Yes it is true ,in fact $f(z)=f(z^*)^*$ for all $f$ which are real for real $z$.

Comment: For the polynomial, you only have $$\sum_{k=0}^n c_kz^k = \overline{\sum_{k=0}^n c_k \overline{z}^k}$$ if all $c_k$ are real.

Comment: No, it's not the same if $\;c_i\notin\Bbb R\;$..at least in the first part.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to prove this theorem, but here is what I prefer to write down:

we know $f$ is entire is really the same as $f$ is just the Taylor series, which has radius of convergence infinity.

Now let $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+.....$

Then $g(z)$ is simply the power series with all the coefficients replaced by their complex conjugate.

Clearly $g(z)$, as a power series, have the same radius of convergence as $f$, so is entire.

This also helps with you to compute your examples.

Actually I thought the hint is "misleading" as it doesn't help compute the examples. But anyway, the hint is correct, you can directly verify the real and imaginary part satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equation, therefore.......

I apologize for the poor notations, I'm new here and haven't figured out how to do Latex.

Comment: You are almost there with the basics of LaTeX, just put the formulas inside (double) dollar signs and check the preview.